# I am unable to use HIDDEN Item in sql query... like fetching data in LOV where hidden Item is used in where clause

Tags: apex, oracle-apex-5

It's a very simple query in select list:

```
select description,code
from table
where flag=:P18_FLAG;
```

It works fine if `:P18_FLAG` is a TEXT ITEM, but when I change `:P18_FLAG` to a hidden item (Value Protected=NO), it stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the cascading LOV Parent Item(s) feature and submit the item.[image: Cascading Lov feature]